# VLC Media Player mark favorites or rate media?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Is it possible to label favorites or rate music using VLC Media Player?

Specifically what I would like to do is that for each album/folder, I want to be able to select and play my highest rated music, create a playlist with those tracks and also be able to copy the highest rated music that is selected to another folder. I have all my music in my external hard drive and I have been manually copying my favorite music to my computer, but this is too tedious.

I'm on Windows 8, using VLC 3.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, VLC is not a library management program. It only plays media.

Some media players also offer library management features, which would include favorites and ratings and such. Some don't offer this. VLC is one of the latter.

Comment: How about being able to copy a the files from a playlist that I make (with the favorite music) to another folder. Can VLC or another program do that?

Comment: VLC supports playlists: https://wiki.videolan.org/Playlist/

Comment: What is the reason for that? If it can display ratings, it would be nothing but useful if it could also set ratings in any way. It doesn't make sense to preclude this feature, is there an issue for that? So far I only know of this issue which I filed: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/26423